# Reading Mircrophone with pyaudio makes the Microphone Symbol flicker on Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, windows-10, pyaudio

I'm using Windows 10.
I copied a salution for microphone reading with pyaudio from the web.

```
import pyaudio
import numpy as np
import pylab
import time

RATE = 44100
CHUNK = int(RATE/20) # RATE / number of updates per second

def soundplot(stream):
    t1=time.time()
    data = np.frombuffer(stream.read(CHUNK),dtype=np.int16)
    pylab.plot(data)
    pylab.title(i)
    pylab.grid()
    pylab.axis([0,len(data),-2**16/2,2**16/2])
    pylab.savefig("03.png",dpi=50)
    pylab.close('all')
    #print("took %.02f ms"%((time.time()-t1)*1000))

if __name__=="__main__":
    p=pyaudio.PyAudio()
    stream=p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16,channels=1,rate=RATE,input=True,
                  frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)
    for i in range(int(20*RATE/CHUNK)): #do this for 10 seconds
        soundplot(stream)
    stream.stop_stream()
    stream.close()
    p.terminate()
```

The program reads microphone input and saves it to an png.
But when I run the programm the microphone symbole on the windows toolbar starts to flicker.
I think this is because i read from the stream not often enough.
Is there a way to tell windows that the microphone is used all the Time?